# React : How to remove duplicate route name in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am working on ReactJS project . Actually , I am using `React-Router 3.2.0` in my project but I have some issues in project . I am using component name as `organization` I defined route for `organization` it working fine but when I click on button to open a registration form in `organization component` it also working fine because I also defined route to open form . Problem is that when I click on menues to open organization or any other page it showing like `organization/organizaton` or `organization/products` . I want to remove second name like `/products` when user click on menu from registration page .

Sorry ! If I made mistake in writing English because I am not speaker .

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router'

// Components
import Dashboard from './../../pages/DashboardPage/Dashboard'
import Organization from './../../pages/Organization/Organization'
import Products from './../../pages/Products/Products'
import SalesOrder from './../../pages/SalesOrder/SalesOrder'
import Purchase from './../../pages/Purchase/Purchase'
import Shipments from './../../pages/Shipment/Shipment'
import Everything from './../../pages/Everything/Everything'
import Report from './../../pages/Report/Report'
import Logout from './../../pages/Logout/Logout'
import OrganizationForm from '../../pages/Organization/OrganizationForm'
import App from './../../../src/App'
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl'
import AppLocale from '../../lang'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
// Routing for pages
class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        const {locale} = this.props
        const currentAppLocale = AppLocale[locale]
        console.log(currentAppLocale)
        return (
            <IntlProvider
                locale={currentAppLocale.locale}
                messages={currentAppLocale.messages}
            >
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path="/" component={App}>
                        <IndexRoute exact component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path="dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route
                            path="organization"
                            exact
                            component={Organization}
                            menu='Organization'
                        />
                        <Route path="products" exact component={Products} />
                        <Route path="sales" exact component={SalesOrder} />
                        <Route path="purchase" exact component={Purchase} />
                        <Route path="shipments" exact component={Shipments} />
                        <Route path="everything" exact component={Everything} />
                        <Route path="reports" exact component={Report} />
                        <Route path="logout" exact component={Logout} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="organization/new" exact component={OrganizationForm} />
                </Router>
            </IntlProvider>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({settings}) => {
    const {locale} = settings
    return {locale}
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {}
)(Routes)
```

**Code to Generate Link**

```
 {menus.map(item => {
          return (
            <Link to={item.name} name={item.name} key={item.name}
              className={this.state.activeMenu === item.name ? 'menu active' : 'menu' }
              onClick={() => this.setState({ activeMenu: item.name })}
              >
              <Icon name={item.icon} size="large"/>
              <span>{item.name}</span>
            </Link>
```

Comment: There is no directly evident issue with the code provided here.  I suspect that you have code elsewhere where you have a `<Link to="organization">` where you need `<Link to="/organization">` (note the leading slash).  Could you provide the code that's generating the links you are clicking on which are creating the problematic URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that with a basename, here is a link to the docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

```
//The base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash.

<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar" />
<Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using React-router `3.2.0` ? It will workable because BrowserRouter is supported by React-Router 4

Comment: I do not believe this is related to the question.  Basename lets you ensure that the base route starts with a path other than "/".  I believe the issue at hand is too much stuff in the path, not too little.